# Authorize.net gives error 290 but no details about what is missing or invalid

Tags: authorize.net, virtocommerce

I'm trying to configure Virto Commerce's Authorize.net plugin and I'm getting back an error 290 when I do a test transaction.
Unfortunately, no other information is provided and there isnt any documentation.
Is there a log file hidden somewhere or something on Authorize.net that will tell me what caused the 290?

Comment: Can you post the entire response from Authorize.Net?

Comment: Error code 290 is `{
  "code" : "290",
  "text" : "There is one or more missing or invalid required fields.",
  "integration_suggestions" : "", 
  "other_suggestions" : ""
 },`.

Comment: From http://test.authorize.net/gateway/transact.dll:The following errors have occurred.
(290) There is one or more missing or invalid required fields.

Comment: In the virto control panel I have the merchant id & transaction key.  Everything else was let as default.  Do we need the MD5 key?  From what Iv'e read so far it doesnt appear to be needed.

Comment: Unfortunately that error is pretty generic so it's hard to tell what's missing. If you could debug and find out what the request looks like going over to Authnet it would be possible to diagnose this. Otherwise all we can do is guess.

Comment: Agreed.  After additional research it turns out  that there are multiple issues.  Most important is the API (SIM) that the module uses is being retired and I can't find the documentation.  After reading the source code and looking at what the module does I figured out that the relay_response url that was being sent was incorrect but given the lack of documentation I can't figure out what it should be.  So I'm switching over to see if I can make the PayPal module work instead.  I just need a way to process credit cards.  Don't care who does it.

Answer (score 0):

It is really frustrating that Authorize.Net doesn't inform you which fields are missing.  However, you can see which fields are required by:

Logging into your merchant account, then go: Account Settings - Payment Forms - Form Fields
Check to see which fields are checked as required.
If you can't add more fields to the payment request, you may need to un-tick some of the required fields in Authorize.Net.